# Why isn't console.log called after an await?

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering why the console.log(123) isn't called after the await in my example test code?

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(
  resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("abc")
  }, ms)
);

async function start() {
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log(123)  
}
start()
```

Comment: you need to resolve the promise, `resolve()`

Comment: @Kakiz Im only testing for understanding. Sorry if it confusing! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the promise `sleep` returns is never settled, so `start` waits forever at the `await`. To settle the promise call `resolve` (or `reject`, but you haven't used that parameter in your promise executor).

```js
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("abc")
        resolve("Done");
    }, ms);
});

async function start() {
    const result = await sleep(1000);
    console.log(123);
    console.log(`Promise fulfillment value: ${result}`);
}
start();
```

Comment: thanks for the good explanation! learned something again :-)